# "Therefore is always" vs "therefore it is always"

Tags: grammar

What sentence is more correct?

- We don't use the alpha color component, therefore it is always the default
  value.
- We don't use the alpha color component, therefore is always the default
  value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're both wrong. You're using *therefore* when you you actually mean *so*.

> We don't use the alpha color component. Therefore it is always the default value.
>
> We don't use the alpha color component, so it is always the default value.

That's speaking grammatically. Semantically, it's an even bigger mess since making something the default value is quintessentially *using* it.

Answer (score 0):

"It" is required.

Some conjunctions, such as *and* and *or*, allow you to delete the common part of the two arms, whether subject:

> John and Jane went to the shop.

predicate:

> John went to the shop and bought some bread.

or various other components:

> John went to the shop and the post office.

*Therefore* does not really play this game:

> ? John wanted some bread, therefore went to the shop.

(I've used the ? rather than * because I'm not certain that everybody would agree that it isn't acceptable. But it's certainly questionable).

If you use it you cannot delete common parts, such as subjects:

> John wanted some bread; therefore he went to the shop.

(I've also changed the comma to a semicolon: *therefore* does not usually coordinate within one sentence.)